# Are all controls in Windows called common controls?

Tags: winapi

I am confused by the term "Common Controls", are Windows controls divided between common controls and non-common controls?

I tried to search for a list of common controls but I couldn't find anything, if not all controls in windows are common controls, can I get a list of the common controls?

Comment: Try google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Did you thought I tried bing? Are all the controls in this list called common controls? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply put, the "common controls" are those implemented by `comctl32.dll`, the first of which made an appearance in Windows 95. They are:

- [Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761881(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [ComboboxEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775738(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Date/time picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761727(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775239(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Hotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775234(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Hyperlink (Syslink)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760704(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [IP address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761374(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Listview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Pager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760857(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Progress bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760818(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Rebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774375(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Status bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760726(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760548(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760435(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760246(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Trackbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760145(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Treeview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759988(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Up/down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759880(v=vs.85).aspx)

They are distinct from the controls implemented by `user32.dll` which are the "original" Windows controls (dating back to 16-bit Windows): `BUTTON`, `EDIT`, `LISTBOX`, `COMBOBOX`, `STATIC` and `SCROLLBAR`.

Answer (score 5):

I would use Windows Controls and Common Controls quite exchangeable, but it seems that if you want to be strict there are (basic) Windows Controls and (enhanced) Common Controls.

[Windows Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773173(v=vs.85).aspx) says that Windows Controls are child windows and that a complete list is available in the [Control Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx). This is quite a long list and includes for example buttons, edit fields, tree views and date and time pickers.

The MSDN page [About Windows Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#system) gives you a list of basic windows classes. The controls listed there are only the basic ones like buttons and edit fields.

The MSDN page [About Common Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775493(v=vs.85).aspx) says that common controls are implemented by the common control library Comctl32.dll. [Creating Common Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298384(v=vs.85).aspx) says that you should load Comctl32.dll by calling [InitCommonControlsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697(v=vs.85).aspx) providing the controls you need. There are [bits for different classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775507(v=vs.85).aspx), for example for tree views and data and time pickers.

Summing it all up: the list in the  [Control Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to be the complete list of all controls. These are either (basic, simple) Windows Controls (for a list see [About Windows Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#system)) or (more complex and more featured) Common Controls (for a list see [INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775507(v=vs.85).aspx)).